# get location data from service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I try to make a locationing service but somehow i cant make it work.
Lat and Lng are always NULL.

I had some exceptions on `locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);` so i put it inside a **run()** method, now exception is gone. What could be the problem?

So what is the solution to make a locationing service work?

Code:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    private LocationManager locManager;
    private LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();

    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private String providerToSend;

    Messenger messenger;
    Timer t = new Timer();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        locListener = new MyLocationListener();
        locationProviderInit();
        startService();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        shutdownService();

    }

    private void startService() {


        locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        String token = new SharedPreffer(this).loadPreferences("token");

            Log.d("Debug - token: ", "Van Token: " + token);

            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    locationProviderInit();

                    if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {

                        Log.d("Debug - lat: ", latitude);
                        Log.d("Debug - lng: ", longitude);

                    } else {

                        Log.d("Debug - lat and lng are: ", "NULL");
                    }

                }
            }, 0, 5000);

    }

    private void locationProviderInit() {

        new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    boolean gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    boolean network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (gps_enabled) {
                        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
                        providerToSend = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                    }

                    if (network_enabled) {
                        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
                        providerToSend = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Debug", e.toString());
                }
            }
        };

    }


    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if (location != null) {
                longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                latitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    private void shutdownService() {
        if (timer != null)
            timer.cancel();
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Timer stopped!!!");
    }

}
```

Comment: What was the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't execute the Runnable in locationProviderInit...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: sorry, i thought it does answer the question - i will clarify: the runnable never runs, so you did not registered for location updates, you can put a break point in the run() function and see it. Without registering to location updates, the onLocationChanged() will never be invoked.

Comment: OK, but some better explanation and wider answer would be much appreciated... This kind of one sentence (or worse one-two words) answers is oftenly considered as an "answer spam" - that should only be a comment... If there is nothing more to say, post it as comment and if the OP consider it as a right answer You still can post that again as an answer claryfying that You are posting that short answer as it did help to solve the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put a debug message inside the method run() within the Runnable object, and see if it has been ever executed?

Defining a Runnable instance without using it ,e.g. within a thread, won't work.

Here are few examples of open source GPS logging services that you can use as guide.

[GPSLoggerService](http://code.google.com/p/gpslogger/source/browse/trunk/GPSLogger/src/com/prom2m/android/gpslogger/service/GPSLoggerService.java)

[GPSLoggingService](https://github.com/mendhak/gpslogger/blob/master/GPSLogger/src/com/mendhak/gpslogger/GpsLoggingService.java)